# rsyslog on debian keeps on stalling

Tags: rsyslog

I'm running rsyslog 5.8.11 on debian 7.11, standard installation (local, no remote logging).

I've noticed that about 2 minutes after being started, rsyslog stops writing messages to the log files. It's still "running", it just doesn't do anything. I can manually restart it, and it works for another couple of minutes.

Any idea how I can fix that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out: another program was stalling.
For some reason, it was making rsyslog stalling, which in turn was making postfix stalling.
Weird!